# How to pass an array to the desired DetailViewController?

Tags: swift, tableview

I have this code

```
var situation = ["11", "12", "13", "14"]
var situation1 = ["21", "22", "23", "24"]
var situation2 = ["31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36"]

var situationD1 = ["11", "12", "13", "14" ]
var situationD2 = ["21", "22", "23", "24"]
var situationD3 = ["31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36"]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
{
    switch section {
    case 0:
        return "One"
    case 1:
        return "Two"
    case 2:
        return "Three"

    default:
        return nil
    }
}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 3
}

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath 
 indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->       UITableViewCell {
    let identifier = "cell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? UITableViewCell

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell!.textLabel.text = situation[indexPath.row]


    }
    if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        cell!.textLabel.text = situation1[indexPath.row]

    }

    if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        cell!.textLabel.text = situation2[indexPath.row]


    }

    return cell!
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    switch section {
    case 0:
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            return searchResults.count
        }
        else {

            return situation.count }


    case 1:
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            return searchResults.count
        }
        else {
            return situation1.count }
  //  default:
   //   return 0

    case 2:
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            return searchResults.count
        }
        else {
            return situation2.count}
    default:
        return 0


    }

}


func filterContentForSearchText (searcText: String) {
    searchResults = situation.filter{($0 as NSString).localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString("\
(searcText)")}
}
   func searchDisplayController(controller:UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
    self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString)
    return true
}

 override func tableView(tableView:UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath){
    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)
    }

}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()

        let destViewController:DetailViewController! = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
            destViewController.situation = situationD1[indexPath!.row]

    }
}
```

Now for all sections of the table including the mass situationD1.
I wish for each section in DetailViewController display data from the appropriate array.
I do not know how to do it.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I'm not quite following what's happening when you run the code: can you give us more detail?  (empty table, bad data, no sections, what?)  Also, please tell us what happens when you put a breakpoint in

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->       UITableViewCell {
```

and

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
```

You look like you are on the right track, but without more detail on what is happening when you run the code, it's hard to tell.

If this is new to you, go ahead and google for  "UITableView swift docs" and look at the UITableView doc as well as the TableView programming guide at Apple.  It will give you a good overview and should help better understand what is going on.  The link right now is (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451)

best o' luck

Comment: When I run the code and click on the cell in the table of section 0, DetailViewController opens with the data from the array situationD1. This is true. When I click on a cell of section 1, DetailViewController opens with data from an array situationD1. This is not true. I want to open in this case the data from the array situationD2. When I click on a cell of section 2, opens DetailViewController with data from an array situationD1. This is not true. I want to open in this case the data from the array situationD3. Thank you.